# Nexus 7 backspace keypress not coming in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, onkeypress, backspace, nexus-7

I have a class that extends GLSurfaceView.
I have handled keyevents for this surface view.
All keys work fine on all other devices except Nexus 7
In Nexus 7 backspace keypress on inbuilt keyboard is not giving event.
But if third party keyboard is used then the backspace key event comes absolutely fine.

Comment: Found a solution 
Moved back from using
 android:targetSdkVersion="16"
to
 android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution 
Moved back from using
 android:targetSdkVersion="16"
to
 android:targetSdkVersion="15"